# Use Find Function to search values in Formulas

Tags: vba, excel

In the first column of my excel sheet I have formulas like `=Rank(J2; J$2:J$237)`. Every result of this is unique. Now I try to find the row of the value 19 using the find function. But whatever I have tried yet `myCell` is always nothing even though I am sure that 19 exists in column one.

```
Set myCell = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=19, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

Could anyone help me out here and tell me what parameters I have to set to use the find function or if it is even possible. Reading the documentation I thought it would be `xlFormulas`, but that seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass parameter `LookIn:=xlValues` to the `Find` function because you are not looking for 19 in the formulas but in the results (=values).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!